# How to play a sound file?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I have found a solution on here to play a sound file in WPF which I extracted into a method and call this method in another method. But the when the `PlaySound()` is called the sound doesn't play. Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening? Also the sound files are marked as content, but changing to type resource didn't remedy the problem either?

My method to play a sound:

```
private void PlaySound()
{
     Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Sounds/jabSound.wav");
     var player = new MediaPlayer();
     player.Open(uri);
     player.Play();
}
```

Then I call the method like this but its doesn't play the sound file, `PlaySound();`

Comment: `the sound doesn't play` What does it mean? Have you any exception?

Comment: No exception, just doesn't play the sound file..the rest of the code within the calling method executes fine so I know its being called.

Comment: How you add the `jabSound.wav` to the project?

Comment: As a `resource` to a folder named `Sounds`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could also use a [`SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(path);
player.Load();
player.Play();
```

Pretty self explanatory.

**BONUS** Here's how to have it loop through asynchronously.

```
bool soundFinished = true;

if (soundFinished)
{
    soundFinished = false;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { player.PlaySync(); soundFinished = true; });
}
```

Opens a task to play the sound, waits until the sound is finished, then knows it is finished and plays again.

Comment: How do I define the path to the file? I tried the full path from the debug folder in quotes but it gives syntax errors..

Comment: @Brian It would be like `"C://Users//name//sound.wav"`

Comment: I tired this but I'm getting `Error 3 Unrecognized escape sequence
` on the file path, the path is exactly as I copied it.

Comment: @BrianJ My bad I meant to use `\\`... Try `"C:\\Users\\name\\sound.wav"`

Comment: Accepted this answer as it worked for me by passing the path as a resource.

Comment: Bonus comment - I also wanted to loop the sound but struggled to get the Task approach to work. Then realized the player.PlayLooping() call does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Don't forget to call Dispose()

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that `MediaPlayer` does not play the music files in embedded resources, quote from  [`Matthew MacDonald book: Pro WPF 4.5 in C#. Chapter 26`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430243651):

> You supply the location of your file as a `URI`. Unfortunately, this `URI` *`doesn’t use the application pack syntax`*, so it’s not 
>   possible to embed an audio file and play it using the `MediaPlayer` class. This 
>   limitation is because the `MediaPlayer` class is built on functionality that’s not 
>   native to WPF—instead, it’s provided by a distinct, unmanaged component of the 
>   Windows Media Player.

Therefore, try setting the local path to the your music file:

```
private void PlaySound()
{
    var uri = new Uri(@"your_local_path", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    var player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.Open(uri);
    player.Play();
}
```

For workaround, see this link:

[`Playing embedded audio files in WPF`](https://web.archive.org/web/20130602042421/http://sekagra.com/wp/2011/12/playing-embedded-audio-files-in-wpf/)

Comment: That sounds right... If I knew for sure, I'd +1 it.

Comment: Link is no more alive.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Anatoly's answer, I would suggest to listen to `MediaFailed` event to check for `MediaPlayer` failure (such as file not found due to wrong path to your .wav file). `MediaPlayer` doesn't throw exception if it fails to load the media file, it triggers `MediaFailed` event instead.

And if you're trying to use relative uri, remember that it means relative to your executable file location. In development phase, it is *usually* inside `bin\debug` folder. So path to your .wav file should be `"../../Sounds/jabSound.wav"`.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("../../Sounds/jabSound.wav", UriKind.Relative);
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.MediaFailed += (o, args) =>
                      {
                          //here you can get hint of what causes the failure 
                          //from method parameter args 
                      };
player.Open(uri);
player.Play();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, Should the audio file be set to `resource` or `content` in this context?

Comment: @BrianJ What you think about deployment strategy?

Comment: I tried your above solution, including adding the sound file to debug but its still not playing the file..any ideas?

Comment: if you put breakpoint at `MediaFailed` event handler and run the project in debug mode, does the event get fired?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on player.MediaFailed and the breakpoint triggers.

Comment: and what you get in `args.ErrorException`? That should give you idea of what need to be fixed

Comment: I want to upvote this for the good info about the Failed event, but downvote it for the bad advice on the relative path. Hmmm... what do do, what to do.