# WPF MediaElement media fails to play

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement in a C# WPF application that I cannot get to play any of my audio files. I have tried .wav, .mp4, and .m4a and none of them have worked. I've used the MediaFailed property to figure out that, well, the media is failing before it loads whenever I start my project. Even with manual controls it fails. I've scoured the internet and cannot find an answer for my particular problem. Please help.

I have the latest version of Windows Media Player (I know that MediaElement needs it to work) on Windows 10 1909. All of my files work in WMP.

XAML:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="mediaContainer">
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaBGM" Source="/Resources/Sounds/BGM/Dungeon1.m4a" Volume="100" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" MediaFailed="MediaElement_MediaFailed" Loaded="MediaElement_Loaded" MediaOpened="mediaBGM_MediaOpened"/>
</ContentControl>
```

EDIT:
I set the absolute path to the sound file and now it loads, but the media still fails.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745364/11954917

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/media-element-in-wpf/

Comment: Set the absolute path to the file. I'm not sure if current directory is the same as you expect.

Comment: @aepot I've set the absolute path to the file now. It successfully loads, but then it fails. Nothing plays.

Comment: What's `fails` means? Exception?

Comment: As with all things dealing with code, the music now magically plays. I don't know why but I'm not going to complain.